# How to create a single link which opens to other links with the respective parameters?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="location.href=this.href+x7.innerHTML;return false;">Link</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="location.href=this.href+x6.innerHTML;return false;">Link 1</a>
```

Hi, I would like to know how you can create a single button which opens both the links along with the parameters as listed above.

Comment: Open where? In different windows/tabs?

Comment: In different windows or tabs both options are fine, I just want the link to pass the parameters invidually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open one in same window and the other in a new window/tab

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/9Lf7r/)

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("link1").onclick=function() {
    var parm6 = document.getElementById("x6").innerHTML;
    var parm7 = document.getElementById("x7").innerHTML;
    this.href="http://www.google.com/search?q="+parm6;
    window.open("http://www.google.com/search?q="+parm7,"_blank");
  }
}
```

Open both in new window

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("link1").onclick=function() {
    var parm6 = document.getElementById("x6").innerHTML;
    var parm7 = document.getElementById("x7").innerHTML;
    window.open("http://www.google.com/search?q="+parm6,"_blank");
    window.open("http://www.google.com/search?q="+parm7,"_blank");
    return false; // cancel the link
  }
}
```

using

```
<a href="#" id="link1">Link 1</a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend you gave the right solution I have been looking for and thanks stackoverflow for helping us get the right solutions through this wonderful forum.